# Strongloop (loopback) class methods

Tags: node.js, methods, model, loopbackjs, strongloop

I have some difficulty understanding how Strongloop models behave. There is a lot of documentation about static and remote methods, but how about general class methods?

Let's say I have a user model, that has a method for showing the full name:

```
module.exports = function (User) {
    User.name = function () {
        return User.firstname + ' ' + User.lastname;
    }
};
```

How do I fetch this user and use the method? I would suppose:

```
var User = app.models.User;

User.findById('559103d66d', function (err, model) {
    console.log(model.name());
});
```

But apparently, the findById returns a JSON object containing all the properties instead of the actual model. So how does one define and use model methods in Strongloop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use 'prototype' property of javascript, if your are planning to use `name()` function on the instance of 'User' model. As follows:

```
User.prototype.name = function () {
   return this.firstname + ' ' + this.lastname;
}
```

and you are good to go.